# Variable length of horizontal summation

Tags: excel

I want to make a formula that uses a reference cell (week number) to identify how many cells a summation formula will use.

For example:
I have a weekly usage of electricity and want a cumulative from week 1 to a week i specify. I have the data horizontally as shown in the image. . If i put the number 5 in the reference cell i want the formula to do a summation of week 1-5.

I know how to do this vertically with the INDIRECT function, but horizontally I can't find out what to do. I would like to do it horizontally since a lot of my other formulas are built around this format.

[image: Example with electricity usage from week 1-6]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `width` parameter of the `OFFSET` function.  For your data above:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(B2,0,0,1,B4))
```

`OFFSET` (and `INDIRECT`) are both volatile functions, which means they recalculate whenever anything recalculates on the sheet.  An NON-volatile version of the above formula might be something like:

```
=SUM(INDEX($2:$2,1,2):INDEX($2:$2,1,2+B4-1))
```

The `INDEX` function was originally volatile, but became non-volatile in Excel '97